# How to remove last element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I'm trying to create a calling pad that reads a maximum of 10 numbers at a time, and displays the numbers as a maximum of 6 numbers in a row. It's working functionally. I want to remove the last number when the user presses the clear button.

I used `$("#calling-pad").last().remove();` to try to remove the last number, but it removes the whole contents and doesn't allow to enter a new number. How can I fix it?

```js
var key = 1;

$("#nine").click(function(){
    if (p === 1) {
        $("#mini-screen").css("display","none");
        $("#number-screen").css("display","block");
        if (key < 11) {
            if ((key % 7) !== 0) {
                $("#calling-pad").append("9");
                key = key + 1;
            }
            else {
                $("#calling-pad").append("<br>");
                $("#calling-pad").append("9"); 
                key = key + 1;
            }
        }    
    } 
});

$("#inner-icon-one").click(function(){
    if (p === 1) {
        $("#mini-screen").css("display","none");
        $("#number-screen").css("display","block"); 
        if (key > 1) {
            if ((key%6) !== 0) {
                $("#calling-pad").last().remove();
                key = key - 1;

                if ( key === 1) {
                    $("#number-screen").css("display","none"); 
                    $("#mini-screen").css("display","block");   
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="calling-pad"> </span>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are just appending numbers to a `span` tag and are not really keeping track of user input.

```
$("#calling-pad").last().remove();
```

Is telling jQuery to remove the full contents because you are not inserting any child elements to the `calling-pad` span.

Therefore you could use an array to keep track of the users numbers or use a counter as I have shown below.

```js
var totalInputs = 0;

$("#insert").on("click", function() {
     totalInputs++;
     var inputText = $("#input").val();
     var id = "calling_" + totalInputs;
     $("#calling-pad").append("<span id='" + id + "'>" + inputText + "</span>");
});

$("#remove").on("click", function() {
    $("#calling_" + totalInputs).remove();
    totalInputs--;
});
```

```css
span {
   display: block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input" /> 
<button id="insert">Insert</button>

<div id="calling-pad">
</div>

<button id="remove">Remove last element</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem - Using 'last' instead of ':last-child'

The jQuery [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) method does not find child elements. Instead, given a collection of elements matching a selector, it filters that collection to include only the last element. Combining this with an id-selector (i.e. `$("#element-id").last()`) is always redundant, since `$("#element-id")` only matches a single element, and the resulting jQuery object is always of size 1. If there's only one element, it's always the last one.

Therefore `$("#calling-pad").last().remove();` is effectively the same as saying `$("#calling-pad").remove();`.

---

#### Solution

Instead, when you're appending data to the `#calling-pad` element, ensure they're included as new elements (e.g. wrapped in `<span></span>` tags):

```
$('#calling-pad').append("<span>9</span>");
```

Then, when you want to remove the last element in the `#calling-pad`, you simply have to do this:

```
$('#calling-pad > span:last-child').remove();
```

This finds all `span` elements that are direct children of the `#calling-pad`, filters that to only include the last element (using [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/)), and then removes that element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#calling-pad").contents().last().remove();
if ($("#calling-pad").contents().last().is("br")) {
    $("#calling-pad").contents().last().remove();
}
```

As you're dealing with textNodes, you need to use .contents() - the `<br>` split them up so no need to parse things, and if you're deleting the last node, you need to delete the last break at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

You need one line to remove last comment... no need to count ids ...
here is snippet ... Cheers Man

```js
$("#insert").on("click", function() {
     var inputText = $("#input").val();
     $("#calling-pad").append("<span>" + inputText + "</br></span>");
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
  $("#calling-pad").children("span:last").remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input" /> 
<button id="insert">Insert</button>

<div id="calling-pad">
</div>

<button id="remove">Remove last one</button>
```